# Is there any way to know the number of bytes transfered in an async_read function if the read handler won't get invoked?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have coded the following **DoRead** function which reads data from the opened serial port, and it works as expected except one thing:

- When the timeout elapses before the read completes, then no read handler will be invoked and I can not get the number of bytes read at this point.

Here is my code:

```cpp
std::size_t wxSerialPort::DoRead(std::string& str, const int timeout)
{
    m_bytes_transferred_read = 0;

    boost::asio::async_read(m_serialPort, boost::asio::buffer(str),
                            std::bind(&wxSerialPort::AsyncReadHandler, this,
                                      std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));

    m_io_context.restart();

    if (timeout == wxTIMEOUT_INFINITE)
    {
        m_io_context.run_until(std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point::max());
    }
    else
    {
        m_io_context.run_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(timeout));
    }

    return m_bytes_transferred_read; // At this point I always get 0 bytes read.
}

void wxSerialPort::AsyncReadHandler(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    m_bytes_transferred_read = bytes_transferred;
}
```

Keep in mind that any variable preceded with ***m_*** is a member variable.

But if I give a small buffer for example to the function, then the read handler will be invoked before the timeout, and I get the actual number of bytes read.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If the timeout expires, *no* bytes were transferred. That is the meaning of the read timeout,

Comment: What if he's implying using transfer_exactly but the exact amount is never read and read times out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out that, boost-asio -**by design**-, **won't** call any IO handler for any of the **io_context::run_for**, **io_context::run_one_for**, **io_context::run_until** and **io_context::run_one_until** functions when the timeout elapses.

And the solution for this problem, would be to provide our own **wait handler** and **cancel** (**basic_serial_port::cancel**) all asynchronous operations associated with the serial port in that wait handler, that in turn will trigger our read handler with a **boost::asio::error::operation_aborted** error code.

And the resulting code will be as follows:

```cpp
std::size_t wxSerialPort::DoRead(std::string& str, const int timeout)
{
    m_bytes_transferred_read = 0;

    if (timeout == wxTIMEOUT_INFINITE)
    {
        m_timer.expires_at(std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point::max());
    }
    else
    {
        m_timer.expires_from_now(std::chrono::milliseconds(timeout));
    }

    m_timer.async_wait(std::bind(&wxSerialPort::AsyncWaitHandler, this,
                                 std::placeholders::_1));

    boost::asio::async_read(m_serialPort, boost::asio::buffer(str),
                            std::bind(&wxSerialPort::AsyncReadHandler, this,
                                      std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));

    m_io_context.restart();
    m_io_context.run();

    return m_bytes_transferred_read;
}

void wxSerialPort::AsyncReadHandler(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    if (error != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted)
    {
        m_timer.cancel();
    }

    m_bytes_transferred_read = bytes_transferred;
}

void wxSerialPort::AsyncWaitHandler(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    if (error != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted)
    {
        m_serialPort.cancel();
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to call `async_read_some` instead of `async_read`.

The [async_read](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read.html) function *ensures* that the requested amount of data is read before the asynchronous operation completes, i.e. it needs enough data to fill the buffer before it calls the read handler.

The [basic_serial_port::async_read_some](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_serial_port/async_read_some.html) method calls the read handler whenever data has been received, regardless of whether the buffer is full or not.

So simply replace the call to `async_read` with:

```
m_serialPort.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(str),
                        std::bind(&wxSerialPort::AsyncReadHandler, this,
                                  std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
```